# powershell script does not fully run

Tags: powershell

I am trying to extract inactive users from AD and save the output in a .csv file. Then, send the file via email to the admins. If I save the script as `###FIRST PART###` only it works fine and saves the .csv file. If in the `###SECOND PART###` I run the `Send-MailMessage` from Powershell it runs perfectly and I receive the email. If I combine them, it does not work. I tried to add a `Start-Sleep -s 15;` but the script terminates after 2 seconds executing correctly the 1st part, it never gets to the 2nd part.

```
###FIRST PART### 
import-module activedirectory 
$domain = "my.domain" 
$DaysInactive = 30
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))

Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp |

select-object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} | export-csv OLD_User.csv -notypeinformation;

###SECOND PART###  
Start-Sleep -s 15;

Send-MailMessage -Attachments .\OLD_User.csv -To myemail@mydomain.com -Subject "Monthly Report - Inactive Users" -From "inactiveuserscript@mydomain.com" -SmtpServer "inbound.mydomain.com"
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong. Sleep shouldn't be necessary. tip: you can replace your custom `Stamp` property with `LastLogonDate` (remember to also specify it in `-Properties` in `Get-ADUser`). It's a built in converted property in the cmdlet/module.

Comment: I could not replicate your issue. I copy and pasted your code and all of it executed. Of course I got an error on the Send-MailMessage, but the error shows that the line executed.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Or is it a cut down example? How is the code being run? In a console? In the ISE (please no)? As a scheduled task? What is the value of $ErrorActionPreference in whatever environment it is being run?How do you know that it never gets to the second part? Have you put in any Write-Host statements to see how far into the code it actually executes?